# How to save multidimensional array into a file or mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I want to track user interaction with a plugin written in `jquery` which is storing some multi-mensional `arrays`. I want to save those `arrays` into `mysql` database or into a file which I can display later.

The array looks like this:

```
var data = [ [381, 143, 0, 0, 0, 250, 1],[367, 147, 0, 0, 0, 250, 2],[367, 147, 0, 0, 1, 249, 3] ];
```

Basically this plugin just records positions into the arrays and displays animation on screen where the user clicks.

Here is an example how this script is working:

```
 var myRecord =new viewRec({interval:250});
 var data = [ [381, 143, 0, 0, 0, 250, 1],[367, 147, 0, 0, 0, 250, 2],[367, 147, 0, 0, 1, 249, 3] ];
 myRecord.setData(data);
 myRecord.play();
```

Comment: So you have the array already and want to store it in the database? You are not showing any code of your current attempt on that. You need to sent the array data to your server, have a server side script store the values in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to `JSON.stringify(data, null, ' ')` to make the array into a JSON and then write the JSON to MySQL.

When you want to get the data, get it from MySQL and do `JSON.parse(datafrommysql);` to get the multidimensional array for your processing needs.

JSON vs XML : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_xml.asp 
Documentation on JSON supported data types : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp 
Documentation on JSON.parse : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp 
Documentation on JSON.stringify : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp